# How to extract text by date range?

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I am trying to extract text from a file according a given date range. The date range will be decided by the user but here I am just using a fixed range.

File content after using `grep` are as follows:

```
ronnie@ronnie:~$ zgrep added new.txt
Jul 02 21:03 : update: added Linkin Park/Living Things(2012)/02 - Linkin Park - In My Remains.mp3
Jul 02 21:03 : update: added Linkin Park/Living Things(2012)/03 - Linkin Park - Burn It Down.mp3
Jul 07 10:33 : update: added Linkin Park/Living Things(2012)/04 - Linkin Park - Lies Greed Misery.mp3    
Jul 09 07:54 : update: added Linkin Park/Living Things(2012)/04 - Linkin Park - Lies Greed Misery.mp3
```

Now, lets suppose I want to extract the text between date `Jul 07` and `Jul 09`. So  I used the below command for that

```
zgrep added new.txt | sed '/"Jul 09"/,/"Jul 07"/p'
```

which gave me the following output

```
Jul 02 21:03 : update: added Linkin Park/Living Things(2012)/02 - Linkin Park - In My Remains.mp3
Jul 02 21:03 : update: added Linkin Park/Living Things(2012)/03 - Linkin Park - Burn It Down.mp3
Jul 07 10:33 : update: added Linkin Park/Living Things(2012)/04 - Linkin Park - Lies Greed Misery.mp3
Jul 09 07:54 : update: added Linkin Park/Living Things(2012)/04 - Linkin Park - Lies Greed Misery.mp3
```

So, as you can see it didn't considered the `range` i gave to sed.

My question is what should be the correct way to extract text according to a date range.

Comment: Are the lines guaranteed to be ordered by date/time?

Comment: @Sorpigal: yes it is ordered by date/time. Actually the file I showed is just a shortened version of `/var/log/mpd.log`.

Comment: I think grep may be more appropriate if your trying to get just the dates

Comment: See my [answer on Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/a/102531/1293). In your attempt in your question, the double quotes are taken literally, but they are not present in the input file. You don't have `-n` to suppress printing non-matching lines. I'm pretty sure you need to specify the range delimiters in the order they appear in the file (Jul 7 then Jul 9).

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: I was missing the order thing. Thanks.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: I am facing another problem. when I use `sed -n -e '/Jul 07/,/Jul 08/p'` it prints the entry with date `jul 09` also and is there anyway I can force sed to check for every date in the given range. lets suppose user enetered `30th june` but my log file doesn't have `30th june` so by default what sed does is it prints nothing when I use `sed -n -e '/Jun 30/,/Jul 09/p'. So, can i force sed to automatically check the next date after that and prints the entries between `jul 02 & jul 09`.

Comment: I can't see any reason that the "Jul 09" line should be output. For checking ranges where there may not be matching range boundaries within the data, see the answer I linked to in my comment above.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: This is my [test file](http://pastie.org/4226443) and when I use `grep add test.txt | sed -n '/Jul 07/, /Jul 08/p'` this is my [output](http://pastie.org/4226449).

Comment: @ronnie: That's because it's still looking for "Jul 08" when it reaches the end of the file. I was confused because I failed to notice that you had changed from "Jul 09" in your question to "Jul 08" in your comment. There's no robust way to get `sed` to do this because it has no concept of dates.

Answer (score 3):

For ordered input,

```
command | sed -n '/^Jul 07/,/^Jul 09/p' inputFile
```

is sufficient.

Comment: @ronnie: did you add `-n` option ?

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close, what you want is this:

```
zgrep added new.txt | sed -n -e '/Jul 09/,/Jul 07/p'
```

Changes were:

- added `-n`, which means lines won't be printed unless you specifically say to with `p`
- added `-e`, just for clarity
- removed your double quotes around the strings. These are not needed because the expression is already enclosed in single quotes and the double quotes do not appear in your file.

Note that this, and your version, will only work if the lines are always ordered by date/time in the first place.

Comment: Your solution works but it only shows the entry with date `jul 09` and it doesn't show's the one with `jul 07`.

Comment: As @dennis mentioned that we `need to specify the range delimiters in the order they appear in the file (Jul 7 then Jul 9).`